# append function in custom div from library

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm new to jquery, means I'm learning it. I have been dealing simple ajax code cause my specification is more in PHP then jquery

Here I need to customize one open source jquery datepicker library, not big library and not big changes.

This datepicker shows calendar only after the button click which button is embedded through jquery, or while `hovering` input field. Snippet has been attached. Everything is working fine.

Just I need - to `append` this calendar in my required div.

So then, need to customize datepicker library. I tried it. For example, the specific div to be appended the calendar directly - `#calendar`, I am trying using `append` every function included in library in this div. For example

```
$('#calendar').getCalendarDivString();
```

but doesn't work.

**Jquery Datepicker library**

```js
function getCalendarDivString(t) {
    var e = '<div id="ndp-nepali-box" class="ndp-corner-all" style="display:none">'
    return e += '<span id="ndp-target-id" style="display:none"></span>', e += '<div class="ndp-corner-all ndp-header">', e += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="prev" title="Previous Month" class="ndp-prev"></a>', e += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="next" title="Next Month" class="ndp-next"></a>', e += '<span id="currentMonth"></span>', e += "</div>", e += '<div id="npd-table-div">', e += "<table>", e += '<tr class="ndp-days">', e += "<th>आ</th>", e += "<th>सो</th>", e += "<th>मं</th>", e += "<th>बु</th>", e += "<th>बि</th>", e += "<th>शु</th>", e += "<th>श</th>", e += "</tr>", e += "</table>", e += "</div>", e += "</div>"
}

function showNdpCalendarBox(t) {
    if (npdCalendarVisible) hideCalendarBox(!1)
    else {
        ndpData[t] && (ndpAttr = ndpData[t])
        var e = $("#" + t).val()
        $("#ndp-target-id").html(t)
        var n = $("#" + t).offset()
        $("#ndp-nepali-box").css("top", n.top + $("#" + t).outerHeight()), $("#ndp-nepali-box").css("left", n.left), showCalendar(e), npdCalendarVisible = !0
    }
}

function setSelectedDay(t) {
    var e = $("#ndp-target-id").html()
    $("#" + e).val(t), ndpAttr.ndpEnglishInput && $("#" + ndpAttr.ndpEnglishInput).val(BS2AD(t)), hideCalendarBox()
}

function showCalendar(t) {
    $("#ndp-nepali-box table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove(), "" === t ? $("#ndp-nepali-box table").append(getDateTable("")) : $("#ndp-nepali-box table").append(getDateTable(t)), "block" == $("#ndp-nepali-box").css("display") && $("#ndp-nepali-box").hide(), $("#ndp-nepali-box").fadeIn(100)
}

function getDateTable(t) {
    var e = "",
        n = ""
    if ("" === t) {
        var a = getNepaliDate()
        return e = getMonthParameters(a), n = getDateRows(e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4])
    }
    return e = getMonthParameters(t), n = getDateRows(e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4])
}

function performSelectMonth(t) {
    showCalendar((ndpAttr.npdYear ? $("#npd-year-select").val() : t) + "-" + $("#npd-month-select").val() + "-01")
}

function performSelectYear(t) {
    showCalendar($("#npd-year-select").val() + "-" + (ndpAttr.npdMonth ? $("#npd-month-select").val() : t) + "-01")
}

function getMonthSelect(t, e) {
    var n = getNepaliMonthsInNepali(),
        a = '<select id="npd-month-select" onchange="performSelectMonth(' + e + ')">'
    return n.forEach(function(e, n) {
        a += '<option value="' + (n + 1) + '"' + (n + 1 == t ? " selected" : "") + ">" + e + "<li>"
    }), a += "<select>"
}

function getYearSelect(t, e, n) {
    var a = '<select id="npd-year-select" onchange="performSelectYear(' + t + ')">'
    for (i = Math.round(n / 2) > 0 && parseInt(e) - Math.round(n / 2) >= 2e3 ? parseInt(e) - Math.round(n / 2) : 2e3; i <= (Math.round(n / 2) > 0 && parseInt(e) + Math.round(n / 2) <= 2090 ? parseInt(e) + Math.round(n / 2) : 2090); i++) a += '<option value="' + i + '"' + (e == i ? " selected" : "") + ">" + englishNo2Nep(i) + "<li>"
    return a += "<select>"
}

function getMonthParameters(t) {
    var e = t.split("-"),
        n = e[0],
        a = e[1],
        s = ndpAttr.npdYearCount || 0
    ndpAttr.npdMonth && ndpAttr.npdYear ? $("#currentMonth").html(getMonthSelect(a, n) + getYearSelect(a, n, s)) : ndpAttr.npdMonth ? $("#currentMonth").html(getMonthSelect(a, n) + " " + englishNo2Nep(n)) : ndpAttr.npdYear ? $("#currentMonth").html(getNepaliMonth(a - 1) + " " + getYearSelect(a, n, s)) : $("#currentMonth").html(getNepaliMonth(a - 1) + "&nbsp;" + englishNo2Nep(n)), nYear = pYear = n, nMonth = parseInt(a, 10) + 1, nMonth > 12 && (nYear++, nMonth = "01"), pMonth = parseInt(a, 10) - 1, pMonth < 1 && (pYear--, pMonth = "12"), $("#prev").attr("onclick", "showCalendar('" + pYear + "-" + pMonth + "-01')"), $("#next").attr("onclick", "showCalendar('" + nYear + "-" + nMonth + "-01')")
    var r = e[2],
        i = numberOfBsDays(n, a - 1),
        d = new NepaliDateConverter,
        o = a + "/1/" + n,
        h = d.bs2ad(o),
        p = h.split("-"),
        l = p[0],
        u = p[1],
        b = p[2],
        c = new Date(l, u - 1, b),
        g = c.getDay()
    return [g, i, n, a, r]
}

function getDateRows(t, e, n, a, s) {
    for (var r = getNepaliDate(), i = r.split("-"), d = i[0], o = get2DigitNo(i[1]), h = get2DigitNo(i[2]), p = "", l = 0; t + e > l; l++) {
        l % 7 === 0 && (p += "<tr>")
        var u = l - t + 1,
            b = "" + n + "-" + get2DigitNo(a) + "-" + get2DigitNo(u),
            c = ""
        c = n == d && get2DigitNo(a) == o && h == get2DigitNo(u) ? "ndp-selected" : u == s ? "ndp-current" : "ndp-date", ndpAttr.disableDaysBefore && parseInt(ndpAttr.disableDaysBefore) > 0 && (ndpAttr.disableBefore = getNepaliFormat(BsAddDays(getNepaliFormat(getNepaliDate()), -1 * parseInt(ndpAttr.disableDaysBefore)))), ndpAttr.disableDaysAfter && parseInt(ndpAttr.disableDaysAfter) > 0 && (ndpAttr.disableAfter = getNepaliFormat(BsAddDays(getNepaliFormat(getNepaliDate()), parseInt(ndpAttr.disableDaysAfter)))), t > l ? p += "<td></td>\n" : (p += "<td class='" + c + "'>", p += ndpAttr.disableAfter && BsDatesDiff(ndpAttr.disableAfter, getNepaliFormat(b)) > 0 || ndpAttr.disableBefore && BsDatesDiff(ndpAttr.disableBefore, getNepaliFormat(b)) < 0 ? "<a class=\"ndp-disabled\" href='javascript:void(0)'>" + englishNo2Nep(u) + "</a>" : "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"setSelectedDay('" + b + "')\">" + englishNo2Nep(u) + "</a>", p += "</td>\n"), l % 7 == 6 && (p += "</tr>\n")
    }
    return p
}

function hideCalendarBox(t) {
    t = void 0 !== t ? t : !0, $("#ndp-nepali-box").fadeOut(100), npdCalendarVisible = !1, t && ndpAttr.onChange && ndpAttr.onChange()
}

function BsAddDays(t, e) {
    var n = new NepaliDateConverter
    return n.add_bs_days(t, e)
}

function BsDatesDiff(t, e) {
    var n = new NepaliDateConverter
    return n.count_bs_days(t, e) + 2
}

function get2DigitNo(t) {
    return t = parseInt(t, 10), 10 > t ? "0" + t : "" + t
}

function getMonths() {
    var t = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    return t
}

function getNepaliMonths() {
    var t = ["Baisakh", "Jestha", "Ashar", "Shrawan", "Bhadra", "Ashoj", "Kartik", "Mangsir", "Poush", "Magh", "Falgun", "Chaitra"]
    return t
}

function getNepaliDaysShort() {
    var t = ["आ", "सो", "मं", "बु", "बि", "शु", "श"]
    return t
}

function getNepaliMonthsInNepali() {
    return ["बैशाख", "जेठ", "अषाढ", "श्रावण", "भाद्र", "आश्विन", "कार्तिक", "मङ्सिर", "पौष", "माघ", "फाल्गुन", "चैत्र"]
}

function getNepaliMonth(t) {
    t = parseInt(t, 10)
    var e = getNepaliMonthsInNepali()
    return e[t]
}

function getCurrentDayName() {
    var t = new Date,
        e = t.getDay(),
        n = Array(7)
    return n[0] = "Sunday", n[1] = "Monday", n[2] = "Tuesday", n[3] = "Wednesday", n[4] = "Thursday", n[5] = "Friday", n[6] = "Saturday", n[e]
}

function getDayFromDate(t) {
    var e = t.split("-"),
        n = e[2],
        a = e[1],
        s = e[0],
        r = new Date(s, a - 1, n),
        i = r.getDay(),
        d = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
    return d[i]
}

function numberOfBsDays(t, e) {
    var n = new NepaliDateConverter
    return n.bs[t][e]
}

function numberOfDays(t, e) {
    var n = new Date(t, e, 0)
    return n.getDate()
}

function AD2BS(t) {
    var e = new NepaliDateConverter
    return e.ad2bs(getNepaliFormat(t))
}

function BS2AD(t) {
    var e = new NepaliDateConverter
    return e.bs2ad(getNepaliFormat(t))
}

function getNepaliDate() {
    var t = new NepaliDateConverter
    return t.ad2bs(getDateInNo("/"))
}

function getDateInWords() {
    var t = getMonths(),
        e = new Date,
        n = e.getDate(),
        a = e.getMonth() + 1,
        s = e.getYear(),
        r = 1e3 > s ? s + 1900 : s
    return n + " " + t[a] + ", " + r
}

function getDateInNo(t) {
    var e = new Date,
        n = e.getDate(),
        a = e.getMonth() + 1,
        s = e.getFullYear()
    return a + t + n + t + s
}

function getNepaliFormat(t) {
    var e = t.split("-"),
        n = e[2],
        a = e[1],
        s = e[0]
    return a + "/" + n + "/" + s
}

function getAdDateInWords(t) {
    var e = getMonths(),
        n = t.split("-"),
        a = n[2],
        s = n[1],
        r = n[0]
    return a + " " + e[s] + ", " + r
}

function getNepaliDateInWords(t) {
    var e = getNepaliMonths(),
        n = t.split("-"),
        a = n[2],
        s = n[1],
        r = n[0]
    return a + " " + e[s] + ", " + r
}

function getCurrentYear() {
    var t = new Date,
        e = t.getFullYear()
    return e
}

function getCurrentMonth() {
    var t = new Date,
        e = t.getMonth() + 1
    return e
}

function getCurrentDay() {
    var t = new Date,
        e = t.getDate()
    return e
}

function makeArray() {
    for (i = 0; i < makeArray.arguments.length; i++) this[i + 1] = makeArray.arguments[i]
}

function englishNo2Nep(t) {
    t = "" + t
    for (var e = "", n = 0; n < t.length; n++) e += convertNos(t[n])
    return e
}

function convertNos(t) {
    switch (t) {
        case "०":
            return 0
        case "१":
            return 1
        case "२":
            return 2
        case "३":
            return 3
        case "४":
            return 4
        case "५":
            return 5
        case "६":
            return 6
        case "७":
            return 7
        case "८":
            return 8
        case "९":
            return 9
        case "0":
            return "०"
        case "1":
            return "१"
        case "2":
            return "२"
        case "3":
            return "३"
        case "4":
            return "४"
        case "5":
            return "५"
        case "6":
            return "६"
        case "7":
            return "७"
        case "8":
            return "८"
        case "9":
            return "९"
    }
}

function NepaliDateConverter() {
    this.bs_date_eq = "09/17/2000", this.ad_date_eq = "01/01/1944", this.bs = [], this.bs[2e3] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2001] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2002] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2003] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2004] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2005] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2006] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2007] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2008] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31], this.bs[2009] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2010] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2011] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2012] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2013] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2014] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2015] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2016] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2017] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2018] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2019] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2020] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2021] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2022] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2023] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2024] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2025] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2026] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2027] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2028] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2029] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2030] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2031] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2032] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2033] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2034] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2035] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31], this.bs[2036] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2037] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2038] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2039] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2040] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2041] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2042] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2043] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2044] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2045] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2046] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2047] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2048] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2049] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2050] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2051] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2052] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2053] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2054] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2055] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2056] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2057] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2058] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2059] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2060] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2061] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2062] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2063] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2064] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2065] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2066] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31], this.bs[2067] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2068] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2069] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2070] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2071] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2072] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2073] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31], this.bs[2074] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2075] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2076] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2077] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31], this.bs[2078] = [31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2079] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2080] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30], this.bs[2081] = [31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2082] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2083] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2084] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2085] = [31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2086] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2087] = [31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2088] = [30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2089] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.bs[2090] = [30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30], this.count_ad_days = count_ad_days, this.count_bs_days = count_bs_days, this.add_bs_days = add_bs_days, this.add_ad_days = add_ad_days, this.bs2ad = bs2ad, this.ad2bs = ad2bs
}

function count_ad_days(t, e) {
    var n = 864e5,
        a = t.split("/"),
        s = e.split("/")
    a[2] = +a[2], a[1] = +a[1], a[0] = +a[0], s[2] = +s[2], s[1] = +s[1], s[0] = +s[0]
    var r = new Date(a[2], a[0] - 1, a[1]),
        i = new Date(s[2], s[0] - 1, s[1]),
        d = Math.ceil((i.getTime() - r.getTime()) / n)
    return d
}

function count_bs_days(t, e) {
    var n = t.split("/"),
        a = e.split("/"),
        s = +n[2],
        r = +n[0],
        i = +n[1],
        d = +a[2],
        o = +a[0],
        h = +a[1],
        p = 0,
        l = 0
    for (l = s; d >= l; l++) p += arraySum(this.bs[l])
    for (l = 0; r > l; l++) p -= this.bs[s][l]
    for (p += this.bs[s][11], l = o - 1; 12 > l; l++) p -= this.bs[d][l]
    return p -= i + 1, p += h - 1
}

function add_ad_days(t, e) {
    var n = new Date(t)
    return n.setDate(n.getDate() + e), ad_month = n.getMonth() + 1, ad_day = n.getDate(), n.getFullYear() + "-" + (ad_month < 10 ? "0" + ad_month : ad_month) + "-" + (ad_day < 10 ? "0" + ad_day : ad_day)
}

function add_bs_days(t, e) {
    var n = t.split("/"),
        a = +n[2],
        s = +n[0],
        r = +n[1]
    for (r += e; r > this.bs[a][s - 1];) r -= this.bs[a][s - 1], s++, s > 12 && (s = 1, a++)
    return a + "-" + (10 > s ? "0" + s : s) + "-" + (10 > r ? "0" + r : r)
}

function bs2ad(t) {
    return days_count = this.count_bs_days(this.bs_date_eq, t), this.add_ad_days(this.ad_date_eq, days_count)
}

function ad2bs(t) {
    return days_count = this.count_ad_days(this.ad_date_eq, t), this.add_bs_days(this.bs_date_eq, days_count)
}
ndpAttr = {}, npdCalendarVisible = "", npdIgnoreMouseUp = !1, ndpData = [],
    function(t) {
        t.fn.nepaliDatePicker = function(e) {
            e = void 0 !== e ? e : {}, ndpAttr = e, this.each(function() {
                var n = t(this).attr("id")
                t(this).addClass("ndp-nepali-calendar"), ndpData[n] = e, ndpAttr.onFocus !== !1 && t(this).attr("onfocus", "showNdpCalendarBox('" + n + "')"), ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButton && t(this).after('<button type="button" class="ndp-click-trigger ' + (ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButtonClass ? ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButtonClass : "") + '" onclick="showNdpCalendarBox(&quot;' + n + '&quot;)">' + (ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButtonText ? ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButtonText : "Pick Date") + "</button>")
            }), t("body").append(getCalendarDivString(ndpAttr)), t(".ndp-nepali-calendar, #ndp-nepali-box").hover(function() {
                mouse_is_inside = !0
            }, function() {
                mouse_is_inside = !1
            }), t("html").mouseup(function(e) {
                t(e.target).is(".ndp-click-trigger") || npdCalendarVisible && !mouse_is_inside && hideCalendarBox(!1)
            })
        }
    }(jQuery)
var mouse_is_inside = !1
arraySum = function(t) {
    for (var e = 0, n = t.length; n; e += t[--n]);
    return e
}
```

```css
style.min.css

.ndp-days th,.ndp-header{font-weight:700;text-align:center}div#ndp-nepali-box{font-family:'Trebuchet MS',Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;border:1px solid #A6C9E2;background-color:#FDFEFE;position:absolute;z-index:9999;padding:1px;margin-top:1px}div#npd-table-div{margin:0}div#npd-table-div table{border-spacing:2px;border-collapse:separate}div#ndp-nepali-box td.ndp-date{margin:1px;padding:1px 2px;border:1px solid #C5DBEC;background:url(images/ndp_date_bg.png) repeat-x #DFEFFC;color:#2E6E9E}div#ndp-nepali-box td.ndp-selected{border:1px solid #FAD42E;background:#FBEC88;color:#363636}div#ndp-nepali-box td.ndp-current{margin:1px;padding:1px 2px;border:1px solid #79B7E7;background:#F5F8F9}div#ndp-nepali-box td.ndp-current a{color:#E17009}div#ndp-nepali-box td.ndp-date a{display:block;color:#1C94C4;text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;width:20px}a.ndp-disabled{color:#ccc!important}div#ndp-nepali-box td.ndp-date:hover{border:1px solid #FED22F;opacity:.8}div#ndp-nepali-box td.ndp-date a:hover{color:#1C94C4}div#ndp-nepali-box table,div#ndp-nepali-box td,div#ndp-nepali-box tr{font-size:12px;height:19px;line-height:19px}.ndp-next,.ndp-prev{position:absolute;top:6px;width:1.3em;height:1.3em}div#ndp-nepali-box a{text-decoration:none}.ndp-header{border:1px solid #4297D7;background:url(images/ndp_bg_wave.png) 50% 50% repeat-x #5C9CCC;color:#fff;font-size:13px;line-height:20px;margin:2px}.ndp-prev{left:7px;background:url(images/ndp_buttons.png) no-repeat}.ndp-prev:hover{background:url(images/ndp_buttons.png) -16px 0 #D0E5F5}.ndp-next:hover{background:url(images/ndp_buttons.png) -48px 0 #D0E5F5}.ndp-next{right:7px;background:url(images/ndp_buttons.png) -32px 0 no-repeat}#currentMonth #npd-month-select,#currentMonth #npd-year-select{color:#000;font-size:12px;font-weight:400}.ndp-corner-all,.ndp-corner-left,.ndp-corner-tl,.ndp-corner-top{-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;-khtml-border-top-left-radius:5px;border-top-left-radius:5px}.ndp-corner-all,.ndp-corner-right,.ndp-corner-top,.ndp-corner-tr{-moz-border-radius-topright:5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;-khtml-border-top-right-radius:5px;border-top-right-radius:5px}.ndp-corner-all,.ndp-corner-bl,.ndp-corner-bottom,.ndp-corner-left{-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;-khtml-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:5px}.ndp-corner-all,.ndp-corner-bottom,.ndp-corner-br,.ndp-corner-right{-moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;-khtml-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-right-radius:5px}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Nepali Calendar</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Datepicker with button</h3>
    <input type="text" id="nepaliDate3" class="nepali-calendar" value=""/><br/><br/>
    <div id='calendar'>How to append calendar in this div without any event ??</div>
  </div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nepaliDate3').nepaliDatePicker({
      onFocus: true,
      npdMonth: true,
      npdYear: true,
      ndpTriggerButton: true,
      ndpTriggerButtonText: 'Date',
      ndpTriggerButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
    });
  });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What datepicker library do you use? If you use the jquery UI datepicker, then you just have to put `$('#calendar').datepicker();`.

Comment: You need to check in library if they provides position relative.

Comment: @Geshode, It is custom `datepicker`. It is not English Calendar. So It is not available in jquery UI datepicker

Comment: do you want to show the calendar inline?

Comment: @Kiranramchandran, exactly in specific div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a the comment given by OP. i modified the script a little which as follows.

i added a new attribute `inLine` to get whether the calendar has to show inline or not.

```
$('#calendar').nepaliDatePicker({
      onFocus: false,
      inLine:true, // Added new attribute
      npdMonth: true,
      npdYear: true,
      ndpTriggerButton: false,
      ndpTriggerButtonText: 'Date',
      ndpTriggerButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
    });
```

and then modified the `datepicker` function

```
    function(t) {
                t.fn.nepaliDatePicker = function(e) {
                    e = void 0 !== e ? e : {}, ndpAttr = e, this.each(function() {
                    console.log(ndpAttr.inLine);
                        var n = t(this).attr("id")
                        t(this).addClass("ndp-nepali-calendar"), ndpData[n] = e,
 ndpAttr.inLine && t(this).append(showNdpCalendarBox(n)) // newly added  - to show calendar inline
    , ndpAttr.onFocus !== !1 && t(this).attr("onfocus", "showNdpCalendarBox('" + n + "')"), ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButton && t(this).after('<button type="button" class="ndp-click-trigger ' + (ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButtonClass ? ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButtonClass : "") + '" onclick="showNdpCalendarBox(&quot;' + n + '&quot;)">' + (ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButtonText ? ndpAttr.ndpTriggerButtonText : "Pick Date") + "</button>")
                    }), t("body").append(getCalendarDivString(ndpAttr)), t(".ndp-nepali-calendar, #ndp-nepali-box").hover(function() {
                        mouse_is_inside = !0
                    }, function() {
                        mouse_is_inside = !1
                    }), t("html").mouseup(function(e) {
                        t(e.target).is(".ndp-click-trigger") || npdCalendarVisible && !mouse_is_inside && hideCalendarBox(!1)
                    })
                }
            }(jQuery)
```

i didn't check no other functionalities.  hope this helps.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7pubr0mf/)

Comment: Thanks ! Man !! Really appreciated your way

Answer (score 0):

After Datepicker code write this, I hope this will work:

```
var calendar = $("input#nepaliDate3").html();
$("input#nepaliDate3").remove();
$("#calender").append(calendar);
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working `"message": "ReferenceError: calender is not defined"`

Comment: Sorry my mistake I write calender than calendar.

Comment: I have edited that post just now and changed calender as calendar.

Comment: Yeah it was `typo` error, But Still not showing, not any errors in `console`

Comment: Okay I'll look for that.